# android admob id

Tags: android, admob

i am very new to the android app development, and i have just almost completed one app finally, and now i am trying to add admob to the app in order to show the ad undernearth.

i have installed that GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid.zip version 6.1.0 and also downloaded the example from google at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals?hl=zh-CN and there is one line

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE);
```

that has bug AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE highlighted.

1. is that i must replace the above AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE by registering and getting an admob account? I have not registered any admob account yet.
2. Is that then i cannot test and preview about the ad if i have no true admob account? are there any ID available solely for testing purposes before i really register for a real one?

The java code is solely copied from the above google website and pasted as follows. android manifest and xml are also same as those in the google example.

```
package com.google.example.ads.fundamentals;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
public class BannerSample extends Activity {
/** The view to show the ad. */
  private AdView adView;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make yourself an account. It's free!

You can't show ads without an publisher id.

[image]

Comment: many thanks!! handling all these admin things is a headache...
Google developer registering for Google wallet
admob for linking to PayPal
and then register for PayPal...

i just want to test...all in all, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for knowing here is not a proper place to ask such question but really dont know where to ask for help...As in the above website picture when I am adding site or app type, one of the field requests for "Android Package URL", my app has not uploaded to the market yet as I do not have the Publisher ID, I wont have any URL for the app yet. I make it as market://details?id=<APPname> but when I press submit, it says it is invalid. What are the proper steps? How could I tackle it? Many thanks!

Comment: use fake package name like `com.dimetil.slot` instead <APPname>, in a future you will change it to your real package name

Answer (score 0):

Use this adunit id for testing  ads:adUnitId="a15391a0507f390"

Answer (score 0):

For **AppID** In new Admob design. You can get in `View setup instructions`.

[image]